# How to create organizational treeview in ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on asp .net with c#. i need to create graphical tree view for organizational hierarchy.can anyone help ?

---

i found this one helpful

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20508/Tree-Chart-Generator

but it is using graphics.

any other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Below is a jQuery example: You just need to render the correct html, via a basic loop in MVC or a repeater in webforms and apply the jQuery plugin

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html